# Goocanvas package

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am trying to install [GPredict](http://gpredict.oz9aec.net/download.php) but it requires a package called **Goocanvas**.

I tried
`sudo apt-get install goocanvas` but the package couldn't be found:

`Unable to locate package goocanvas`

What is Goocanvas and how do I install it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

[GooCanvas](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GooCanvas) is a GTK+ widget that uses the Cairo to draw.

You can download [version 2.0](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/goocanvas/2.0/o) from the link. You need `goocanvas-2.0.0.tar.gz`. After downloading extract the file and copy the content over to a directory and then run the `install-sh` script. Mind that there is also an install.sh script (see the INSTALL document for more).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update your packages and then install it by just typing:-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0-9
```